# How to google sign out in back-end using google sign-in api?

Tags: google-signin

I am using google sign-in for website. 
I want those who are using our g-suite domain can sign in my application.

So I followed the tutorial the authenticate with backend server once more. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth. 
I checked idToken and want people who are not using our domain can not sign in.

Can I google sign-out in back-end? 
and Please let me know the only users using our g-suite domain can sign in!

Thank you.

Comment: Check the hd claim in the ID token as described in the documentation you linked to

Comment: @StevenSoneff I did. but  I don't know what to do when hd claim is different from our g-suite domain. Even though it is different, It still sign-in client site. That's why I want to google sign-out in back-end server.